# Understanding fluid flow velocity vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

Fluid flow velocity field is usually described by the following vector field:

$$\mathbf{u}(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)=u_x(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)\mathbf{i}+u_y(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)\mathbf{j}+u_z(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)\mathbf{k}$$

where $x,y,z$ are positions of bundle at time $t$. However I sometimes see that $\mathbf{u}$ is defined by

$$\mathbf{u}(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)=\frac{dx}{dt}\mathbf{i}+\frac{dy}{dt}\mathbf{j}+\frac{dz}{dt}\mathbf{k}$$

So it follows that

$$u_x(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)=\frac{dx}{dt}(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)$$
$$u_y(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)=\frac{dy}{dt}(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)$$
$$u_z(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)=\frac{dz}{dt}(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)$$

Is that right? It is weird to me that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is a function of $x(t),y(t),z(t),t$. I am struggling to understand which quantities $u_x,u_y,u_z,x,y,z$ depend on.

Comment: You are just a bit lost in notation. $\mathbf{u}(x,y,z,t)$ describes a vector field as a $\mathbb R^3$-valued function on $\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R\,.$ In contrast: $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ is a curve in $\mathbb R^3$ whose tangent vectors coincide with vectors from the field at the points $(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. Ah, so parameters $x,y,z$ do not depend on time?

Comment: Not when considered as the arguments of the field $\mathbf{u}\,.$ You can make the notation easily disambiguous when you write the curve as $t\mapsto (\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t),\gamma_3(t))$ for example. Avoid same letters for different things.